# Put a read-write object lock on every member variable access in a C++ class to achieve synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, oop

I have a huge class X with ~40 complex members and many read/write function calls (which can call each other) which I want to make it thread-safe. One simple approach would be to add an object lock in the implementation wherever someone is trying read/write a specific member. But that would result in adding/modifying a lot of code wherever any of the members are being accessed. Aside from refactoring so much code, it would make a simple function complex to understand for a normal reader. Also, anyone updating the class in future has to be very careful to avoid creating deadlock possibilities.

Is there any simple way to achieve this read-write synchronization?

Comment: Are you sure that per-member locks would even solve the problem you want to solve?  e.g. what if a thread needs to change two different member-variables at the same time (i.e. without any chance of another thread seeing variable A updated but variable B not updated)

Comment: Making each data member thread-safe does not guarantee that every member function will be thread-safe. Consider a function that modifies **two** member variables... Thread safety has to be **designed in** to a class. You generally can't hack it in afterwards.

Comment: You can't solve this at the member level because it does not protect class invariants from concurrent calls.

Comment: You guys are right. Just member-lock won't make the class thread-safe. Object level lock would solve my problem.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: btw I found it hard to read past the first sentence, because a class with ~40 members alone sounds scary. Getting threadsafety right is complicated enough, so I would fix that first. Without a concrete code your question is too vague imho. There is no simple recipe for multithreading, so the most sincere answer you can get is: No.

Comment: Locking the entire class would "work", but it's basically saying "force everything this class does to be single threaded". What you want to consider is what members a method would modify, and if that conflicts with anything else in your class. Secondly, consider the difference between read or write locks

Comment: The whole point of using mutexes is to protect _relationships_ between different variables. Each lock in the program protects a different relationship. Independently locking each variable access accomplishes nothing because it completely ignores relationships. A global lock fails because of what Rogue said (immediately above.) You have to understand which relationships need protection in order to know what to lock and when.